# Who can modify a locked post for me? I found an invalid URL that needs to be updated

Tags: support, edits, specific-question, locked-posts, historical-lock

The question is this: [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

There is a link to [Git guide](http://www.sourcemage.org/Git_Guide), but that does not work.
It should be **[Git guide](https://sourcemage.org/Git%20guide)** (without underscore)

I have sufficient reputation to perform this action on regular questions, but not on a locked one.

Comment: They use a whitespace in the url? ... that's something. Mods should be able to edit locked post. As far as I know regular users can't.

Comment: @Tom Yes, mods should be able to do it, but I also can't flag the question to draw their attention. Meta seemed the only way to go...

Comment: Related: [Some rational behind not allowing flags for historically locked posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247503/1099857).

Comment: But the space must encoded as `%20`(?).

Answer (score 21):

Generally the historical significance lock means "this isn't useful here but was at one point and we want to honor its past life". That means it's not *worth* updating. If it's worth updating it should probably have another lock type applied like a Wiki lock... but coming here to Meta is the right call if you want a locked post edited or its lock type changed/removed.

Personally I think the post should probably just be deleted, because "exhaustive guide to X product" is not what the site is for, and will be out of date as soon as the product is updated. In this case, the entire thread has been static since 2011. Much of the content there is surely stale or has rotted away entirely (for links to off-site resources).